# \rule doesn't work inside an \xdef command

Tags: macros, expansion

This code:

```
 \documentclass{article}  
 \begin{document}  
 \def\a{}  
 \newcounter{mycounter}  
 \def\b#1{  
 \def\p{#1}  
   \ifnum\value{mycounter}=0  
       \long\xdef\a{\a\rule{3mm}{3mm}\par #1}  
   \else  
       \long\xdef\a{\a #1\ }  
  \fi  
 }  
 \b{A}\b{B}\b{C}\b{D}\b{E}\b{F}  
 \setcounter{mycounter}{1}  
 \b{G}\b{H}\b{I}\b{J}\b{K}  
 \a  
 \end{document}
```

throws the ERROR:

```
 "!Paragraph ended before \@newctr was complete.<to be read again>\par b{A}"
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 5):

It can't work like that: `\rule` does assignments that are not performed in an `\xdef`.

You probably want to say

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\a\expandafter{\a\rule{3mm}{3mm}\par #1\ }
```

and similarly for the other line. The `\long` is useless, since `\a` has no arguments.

It seems that you want to add something to the expansion of `\a`, but `\xdef` does "expansion all the way", while you need to get only at the first level expansion of `\a`. The sequence of `\expandafter`'s will do just it. However there's a more efficient way to define your macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\b#1{%
  \def\p{#1}%
  \ifnum\value{mycounter}=0  
    \g@addto@macro\a{\rule{3mm}{3mm}\par #1}%
  \else  
    \g@addto@macro\a{#1\ }%
  \fi  
}
\makeatother
```

The macro `\g@addto@macro` is in the LaTeX kernel and its effect is exactly to append (globally) the second argument to the replacement text of the first argument, which should be a macro.

Comment: @Philipp: well, no; `\xdef` wants to expand all the way and it will find a previously added `\rule`; `\noexpand` acts only once and when the token after it is put into a replacement text it will be expanded when needed.

Comment: Then `\xdef\a{\unexpanded\expandafter{\a\rule...#1}}`. Also, you need to double `#` in your first example.

Comment: @Bruno: where is it necessary to double the `#`?

Comment: `\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\a\expandafter{\a\rule{3mm}{3mm}\par #1\ }` produces the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \a.` EDIT: I didn't realize that it was within some other command, sorry.